# Chrome requiring quicktime, but OS X is saying it's built in. How do I play quicktime movies in chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, h.264, quicktime, aac

So in our application, a video preview is displayed after it is uploaded.  On my computer, however I'm getting a thumbnail that says 'plugin missing' and upon further inspection it says to install the quicktime plugin.

However, the link provided by Chrome to install the plugin leads to a page on apple's website which says 'quicktime plugins don't need to be installed anymore.'

Some details:

- Video Extension: .mov
- Codec: H.264, AAC (which may be what is in question here)
- Chrome Version: Version 39.0.2171.71 (64-bit)
- OSX Mavericks

How do I go about making videos play on my machine, as well as making sure that they show up in the production environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome has removed support for plugins like Quicktime. Most likely you are also using Chrome 64bit. The Quicktime Plugin was only for 32bit.

HTML5 supports videos out of the box so the browser developers of IE, Firefox and Chrome do not see any more use for such plugins.